# django template get key and value seperate to display

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-templates, django-admin

```
In django template i am getting the value like :
```

{"A":"12","B":"13"}

how can i display values in template through loop like :

A - 12
B - 13

Can anyone have any idea please help me related this

Comment: Could you be a little more specific about what problem you're facing? It'd be easier to help if you shared your view function and the template file you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this. it's as simple as that

```py
list = {"A": "12", "B": "13"} # your list

{% for key, value in list.items %}
    {{key}} - {{value}}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this,

```
{% for key, value in your_dict_name %}
   <li>{{key}}-{{item}}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I tried but it returning me the error like :Need 2 values to unpack in for loop; got 1.

Comment: please post, what you have tried & what error you got

Comment: You probably need to add `.list` after `your_dict_name`. Also note that the answer says `key, value` but then uses `{{ key }}` and `{{ item }}`. These need to be consistent.